# CSS DIV Layout over Grid

Tags: css, html

[image]

Is it possible to get this Layout using div's

Comment: the answer is yes it is possible.

Comment: use table to create this

Comment: check this. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this with floats and negative `margin-top` on `.e`. With masonry you don't need `margin-top` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1469/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.a,
.d {
  width: 33.3333333%;
  height: 66.67%;
}
.b,
.e {
  width: 66.67%;
  height: 33.3333333%;
}
.e {
  margin-top: -33.3333333%;
}
.c {
  width: 33.3333333%;
  height: 33.3333333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="a item">a</div>
  <div class="b item">b</div>
  <div class="c item">c</div>
  <div class="d item">d</div>
  <div class="e item">e</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution i was looking for :)

Comment: This answer is more flexible then mine. Will leave mine up as an "alternative".

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

I made a fast snippet for you. Using `position: absolute`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.a {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #C2C2C2;
}

.c {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.d {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

.e {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
  <div class="e"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code using table

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;

}

td
{
    padding:10px;
  }
```

```html
<table  >
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">A</td>
    <td colspan="2">B</td>
    </tr>
  
    <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td rowspan="2">D</td>
    </tr>
  
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">E</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a"><span>A</span></div>
  <div class="b"><span>B</span></div>
  <div class="c"><span>C</span></div>
  <div class="d"><span>D</span></div>
  <div class="e"><span>E</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
span{    
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 25%;
   }

a {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color:#f2f2f2;
 border:solid 1px #333;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color:#d9d9d9;
  border:solid 1px #333;
}

.c {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:#bfbfbf;
  border:solid 1px #333;
 }

.d {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color:#a6a6a6;
  border:solid 1px #333;
  }

.e {
position: absolute;
left: 8px;
top: 100px;
width: 91px;
height: 50px;
background-color:#808080;
border: solid 1px #333;
}
```

Link for above code here https://jsfiddle.net/romesh60/odo4r5aq/2/